# What a vertical bar means in a PropertyGroup .csproj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj

I have a PropertyGroup like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;X86</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to know what the vertical bar (**|**) means when it is placed between parameters in the Condition attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything - it's just a way of separating the configuration and platform.

Note that these aren't really *parameters* in a condition attribute - they're just property values which are replaced with the MSBuild property. `|` is unlikely to be part of a configuration or platform name, so it's a good choice as a separator.

You could have a condition of `"'$(Configuration)/$(Platform)'=='Debug/x86'"` just as easily, for example. `|` is just more conventional.